# Send email notification when post type product is publish from pending status

Tags: customization

I want to send email to the respected user whose product is getting Publish from Pending status. I am using the following code but no mail receives.

```
add_action("publish_post", "on_publish_pending_post", 10, 1);

function on_publish_pending_post($post) {

    // A function to perform actions when a post is published.

    if ($post->post_type == 'product') {

        $name = get_the_title($post->ID);

        // get email from custom field
        // $author = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $user_email, true );

        $to_email = $author->user_email;

        echo $to_email;
        exit();

        $fromMail = "approve@openvectors.net";
        $subjectMail = "Design Approval Success";
        $content = '<p>Your Design has been published !!!</p>';

        $headersMail  = '';
        $headersMail .= 'From: ' . $fromMail . "\r\n";
        $headersMail .= 'Reply-To: ' . $fromMail . "\r\n";
        $headersMail .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headersMail .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        mail($to_email, $subjectMail, $content, $headersMail);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. The hook, you're trying to use, is called from function `wp_transition_post_status()`:

```
function wp_transition_post_status( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
   // 
   // ...
   //
   do_action( "{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}", $post->ID, $post );
}
```

So, to execute code when **product** status changes add function to hook `publish_product`.
The first argument passed to the function is `$post_id`, not `WP_Post` object.
Last thing, checking the type of post in your function `on_publish_pending_post` is unnecessary, because hook is for a specific type ( "publish_**post**", "publish_**product**" ).

**Try this code**:

```
add_action("publish_product", "on_publish_pending_post", 10, 2);

function on_publish_pending_post($post_id, $post) {

    $auth_id = (int)$post->post_author;
    $user = get_userdata($auth_id);
    if ( $user === false )
        return;
    $to_email = $user->user_email;

    $name = get_the_title($post_id);

    $fromMail = "approve@openvectors.net";
    $subjectMail = "Design Approval Success";
    $content = '<p>Your Design has been published !!!</p>';

    $headersMail  = '';
    $headersMail .= 'From: ' . $fromMail . "\r\n";
    $headersMail .= 'Reply-To: ' . $fromMail . "\r\n";
    $headersMail .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headersMail .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // ------ 
    // echo "<br>recipient: " . htmlspecialchars($to_email);
    // echo "<br>sender: " . htmlspecialchars($fromMail);
    // echo "<br>post_title: " . htmlspecialchars($name);
    // exit();
    // ------

    mail($to_email, $subjectMail, $content, $headersMail);
}
```

Comment: I have modified the code below , but its not working.

Comment: add_action("publish_product", "on_publish_pending_post", 10, 2);
function on_publish_pending_post($post_id, $post) {
    if ($post) {
        //my above code
    }
}

Comment: You are using undefined `$author` variable. @PuspalataPanigrahi

Comment: how to resolve the above code. Please help to moderate it.

Comment: uncomment the lines between `// -----` and try to "publish" (not "update") product  
@PuspalataPanigrahi

Comment: Still not getting any email after publish the product.

Comment: But after you uncomment `echo` and `exit()`, do you see the text? If the function `on_publish_pending_post` has been called, you will see recipient email and title of the post (product). @PuspalataPanigrahi

Comment: Yeah, I am able to see email and title.

Comment: Now you have to determine why `mail()` does not work. Is PHP mail function configured?

Comment: yes, in other pages mail() is working. Only here its not working.

Comment: Hey, I am seeing here the recipient mail id is showing of admin mail id not the product's user mail id. And the mail also sending to admin' mail id not the product user's mail id.

Comment: Sorry i am unable to get you. could you please rewrite the above code(provided by you) where the user mail id can receives the mail.

Comment: Do you want to send a message to email stored in custom field?  You have in code this comment: `// get email from custom field`.

Comment: No, here email is not custom field. I have copied this code from another discussion that's why i commented.

Comment: So who should receive an email?

Comment: Product's vendor, means the vendor who added product. I want to send email to that product's vendor mail id.

Comment: It's a commercial plugin, I don't know it and I can't help finding a vendor email.